# Angularjs checkbox group validation (dynamic options)

Tags: angularjs, validation, checkbox, angularjs-ng-form

Let's say I have this question object:

```
$scope.question = {
    id: 1,
    question: 'q?',
    required: true,
    control: {
        type: 'multiple_check',
        options: [{
            value: '1st option'
        }, ... ]
    }
}
```

And this form:

```
<form name="s.form" novalidate>
    <h1>{{ question.question }}</h1>
    <label ng-repeat="option in question.control.options">
        <input type=" name="xxx"
            ng-model="question.answer[$index]" ng-required="question.required" />
        {{ option.value }}
    </label>
</form>
```

And I'm stuck now with validation.

I've [**created a pen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LygYmB) for this.

**{{ s.form.$valid }}** should give me true when form is valid, but it returns true only when all checkboxes in group are checked

**{{ s.form['xxx'].$valid }}** should give me true when at least one checkbox is checked, but it actually returns true only when the last checkbox is checked

I want to be able to choose at least one checkbox (one or more) from the group. When at least one is checked the form and group will be valid.

How can I achieve that? Already tried many things but can't make this to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own validation by watching checkbox as bellow

```
$scope.$watch( "question.control.options" , function(n,o){
    var trues = $filter("filter")( n , {value:true} );
    $scope.flag = trues.length;
}, true );
```

Notice: The value of a checkbox must be a boolean so change your question's value as

```
$scope.question = {
    id: 1,
    question: 'q?',
    required: true,
    control: {
        type: 'multiple_check',
        options: [{
            value: false,
            label: '1st option'
        }, ... ]
    }
}
```

and your view as

```
<form name="s.form" novalidate>
    <h1>{{ question.question }}</h1>
    <label ng-repeat="option in question.control.options">
        <input type=" name="xxx"
        ng-model="question.control.options.value" ng-required="question.required" />
        {{ option.label }}
    </label>
</form>
```

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/JBwmA/) make this approach

Answer (score 0):

This was actually hard but I think it works now.
[Here's working demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LygYmB)

For those who want to know I've included [this module](https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model) in my app.

Then changed the HTML code to:

```
<form name="s.form" novalidate>

   form valid? <b>{{ s.form.$valid | json }}</b>

   <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
        <h1>{{ question.question }}</h1>
        <label ng-repeat="option in question.control.options">
            <input type="checkbox" name="xxx_{{ question.id }}"
            checklist-model="question.answer" checklist-value="option" ng-required="question.required && !question.answer.length" />
            {{ option.value }}
        </label>

        <p>question valid? {{ s.form['xxx_'+question.id].$valid | json }}</p>
        answer: {{ question.answer }}
    </div>

</form>
```